# IE8 stretches background image outside of DIV

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

```
<div id="subpageMain">    
<div id="subpageHeaderImageSection">
    <div id="subpageHeaderLeft">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

#subpageHeaderImageSection {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
#subpageHeaderLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../theImages/subpageHeaderImage.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#subpageMain {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 295px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 43px;
    top: 50px;
 }
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Why does IE8 take the background image and stretch it too much that the right content doesn't show and goes out of the screen?

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support the CSS `background-size` attribute (see [the compatibility table at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility)). To support IE8, you'll need to use an `<img>` element instead and set `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;`.

Comment: Tried that already. And for some reason it's not doing anything. The image is still stretched outside the DIV :/

Comment: I had the IE8 version still displaying the old DIV. I removed it and it's working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 can't stretch the background out of the div. However, it looks like the div with id `#subpageHeaderLeft` is stretched to the right due to the fact that it has `width:100%`

Comment: All the other browsers are working fine, even IE10. But the only issue is in IE8. Any way to fix that?